# Insert values to a table in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created the relation

```
disaster(cname, dyear, etype, casualties)
```

cname and dyear are primary keys. etype is a foreign key.

and i am trying to insert values to it.

```
insert into disaster values
('Kagoshima', 1993, 'flood', 2600),
('Pasto', 1993, 'volcano', 45);
```

and i am getting this message:

> " ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "disaster_pkey"
> SQL state: 23505 Detail: Key (dyear)=(1993) already exists."

Why is that?

Comment: Because you already have rows in the table that have values you are trying to insert.

Comment: the table is empty. those values are the first im inserting

Comment: The error message clearly states that you got a unique constraint on the column `dyear` and you try to insert two rows with the same year 1993

Comment: only dyear was primary key. changed it cname and dyear to be both primary keys and it works